# Pass value dynamically to data-* attribute [Angular2]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to write a component, which basically display a different icon based on its input. The icon framework is expecting it in the following format:

```
  <span class="icon icon-generic" data-icon="B"></span>
```

So `data-icon="B"` describes basically which icon to display. I would like to pass this symbol dynamically. Something like:

```
  <span class="icon icon-generic" data-icon={{symbol}}></span>
```

But this seems not to work. :-/ Is there a way to do this without creating the html in my Component class and appending it to the html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attribute bindings need the `attr.` prefix

```
attr.data-icon={{symbol}}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
 <span class="icon icon-generic" [attr.data-icon]='symbol'></span>
```